# Override touchesBegan

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I am currently developing an iOS app using swift. I used override to write my own tocuhesBegan and tochesEnded functions. Now when I use self.button.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    for touch in touches {
        var tap = touch as? UITouch
        var touchPoint: CGPoint = tap!.locationInView(self)
        self.touchDown(touchPoint)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    self.releaseTouch()
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
}

func touchDown(point: CGPoint){
    if rippleEffect == true {
        touchView.frame = touchViewInitFrame
        self.addSubview(touchView)
        var touchViewFrameXPosition: CGFloat = point.x - (frame.size.width) / 2
        println("X position = \(touchViewFrameXPosition)")
        var touchViewFrameYPosition: CGFloat = -(self.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.height) / 2
        touchViewFrame = CGRectMake(touchViewFrameXPosition, touchViewFrameYPosition, frame.size.width, frame.size.width)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.touchView.frame = self.touchViewFrame
            }, completion: nil)
    }

}

func releaseTouch(){
    if rippleEffect == true {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.touchView.removeFromSuperview()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

it doesn't go to the function I specified in the selector. Is anyone else having this issue or does anyone know what's going on?

Here is the code that I used where I am having the issue. It is a subclass of UIButton.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does overriding touchesBegan have to do with your button's action method? Are you overriding touches began in a custom button class? You should show the code for where you call addTarget:action:, and your implementation of the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override any of the touches methods, you are supposed to override all four *and* call super.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    //your code
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    //your code
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    //your code
}
-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I tried that and it didn't help. I appreciate you trying though.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have two different handles for your view and your button, to prove that try to touch anywhere else in the screen and your touch will be detected, however while pressing the button the touch is handle and never pass to the other handlers. You have to options, intercept all messages and handle if it should be passed or not for the original handles before/after you do what you need to do, or implement the button handler and make it pass the message up the chain:

[From the apple documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9)

> Overriding hit-testing ensures that the superview receives all touches
>   because, by setting itself as the hit-test view, the superview
>   intercepts and receives touches that are normally passed to the
>   subview first. If a superview does not override hitTest:withEvent:,
>   touch events are associated with the subviews where they first
>   occurred and are never sent to the superview.

Comment: How would I go about implementing those two options?